# Is there an other way to add calculated information to a table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table on BigQuery with some information and need to create another table with aggregated information by name with columns that have values with some condition.

Here is an example of a table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (
ID INT,
NAME CHAR,
ORDER_ID INT,
VALUE INT
);

INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7369,'SMITH',1,5);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7499,'ALLEN',2,10);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7521,'JONES',3,15);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7566,'JONES',4,5);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7568,'JONES',5,10);
```

Here is simple aggregate by name:

```
SELECT name as client_name, min(order_id) as f_order,
max(order_id) as l_order, sum(VALUE) as total_order_value
FROM emp
GROUP BY name
```

Output:

```
client_name|f_order|l_order|total_order_value    
ALLEN      |2      |2      |10
JONES      |3      |5      |30
SMITH      |1      |1      |5
```

And needs add one more column "f_order_value" which has value from column "VALUE", when  f_order=order_id:

```
client_name|f_order|l_order|total_order_value|f_order_value    
ALLEN      |2      |2      |10               |10
JONES      |3      |5      |30               |15
SMITH      |1      |1      |5                |5
```

So try create virtual table and works with it, but it doesnt work due to i don't use any aggragations in code, also I do not fully understand how to use the virtual table:

```
with first_table as (SELECT name as client_name,
min(order_id) as f_order, max(order_id) as l_order,
sum(VALUE) as total_order_value
FROM emp
GROUP BY name)
select first_table.*, IF(f.f_order=e.order_id, o.VALUE,null) as
order_value from first_table f
join EMP e on f.client_name=e.name group by name
```

Error:

> Star expansion expression references column site which is neither grouped nor aggregated at

Comment: It sounds like you want one record per last name when there are duplicates then you want an additional sum for the first record with duplicate last names, is that correct?

Comment: nope, there no duplicates, i  only need value from the first records

Comment: Do you have your table on BigQuery or CloudSQL? Your SQL looks mysql.

Comment: I think if you just get rid of the group by in the outer query and replace outer join with a left join, all should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name AS client_name, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(order_id AS f_order, value AS f_order_value ) ORDER BY order_id LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*,
  MAX(order_id) AS l_order, 
  SUM(VALUE) AS total_order_value
FROM `project.dataset.emp`
GROUP BY name
```

if to apply to sample data from your question  - result is

```
Row client_name f_order f_order_value   l_order total_order_value    
1   ALLEN       2       10              2       10   
2   JONES       3       15              5       30   
3   SMITH       1       5               1       5
```

Comment: @ Mikhail - sure, I've had less reputation before for hit)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then one option would be to use the `MIN` analytic function in a CTE, and then subquery:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY name) min_order_id
    FROM emp
)

SELECT
    name,
    MIN(order_id) AS f_order,
    MAX(order_id) AS l_order,
    SUM(VALUE) AS total_order_value,
    SUM(CASE WHEN order_id = min_order_id THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS f_order_value
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    name;
```

[image]

### Demo

A conditional sum of `VALUE` for each person added to your current `GROUP BY` query is the basic solution.  But the difficulty here is that we need to know what the minimum `order_id` is for each person, before we aggregate.  I could not find a way to do without first scanning the table once (hence the CTE used above).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value from the minimum order id in BigQuery, I would recommend:

```
SELECT name as client_name, MIN(order_id) as f_order,
       MAX(order_id) as l_order,
       SUM(VALUE) as total_order_value,
       ARRAY_AGG(value ORDER BY order_id LIMIT 1)[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] as min_order_value
FROM emp
GROUP BY name;
```

BigQuery doesn't directly support a "first" aggregation function (although there is a `first_value()` window function).  However, the `array_agg()` method is commonly used.

No subquery, CTE, or `JOIN` is required.